# Как получить ftp

Tags: ftp

Есть хостинг на котором несколько сайтов, как получить ftp доступ к каждому сайту отдельно?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что подобные вопросы решают с техподдержкой. Или читают документацию и справку на хостинге.

Answer (score 2):

Назначить каждому пользователю FTP домашний каталог, который будет корневой папкой сайта